# Find : $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k(k+1)}$

Tags: inequality, tangent-line

I'm try to find this lim
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^{k}(k+1)}$
Is this limits can be done by integral !? 
Or inequality
Someone help me hints me 
Thanks!

Comment: We can write it as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{k+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n+1}-1\bigg]=e-1.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Recall that 
$$(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k} x^k$$
so $$\frac1x\int_0^x(t+1)^ndt=\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{x(n+1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{{n\choose k}x^k}{k+1}$$
so $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+1)}=\frac{(\frac1n+1)^{n+1}-1}{\frac1n(n+1)}$$
thus your limit is 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(\frac1n+1)^{n+1}-1}{\frac1n(n+1)}$$

Comment: Thanks! Good idea 

Comment: You are very welcome :)